How can I stop keyPressed from repeatedly being called?
When I press an arrow key, keyPressed is called once, and then after a delay it is called very rapidly, like when holding down a key to type a long string of letters like so: eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    System.out.println(e); //this prints repeatedly while any key is held down
}

Is there a way to stop it from being called more than once?
I'm planning on adding a boolean to store true when an arrow key is pressed and false when it is released, and then have an if loop set up inside the keyPressed so it doesn't activate multiple times, but having to do all this makes me think there is a simpler solution.

Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review How to Ask a Good Question. Please edit the question to show  a Minimal Reproducible Example.

You don't, that's how the OS is reporting the events.  If you wish to only react to the first press, set a flag in the keyPressed method and reset it in the keyReleased method - you should also be using Key bindings in most cases. I'd use a enum and a Set to determine when a key is active or not, but that's me

Welp, thanks for letting me know. Should I delete this question now because there's no real answer, or should I just leave it?

If you were to elaborate on what you were actually trying to do, someone may be able to point you in a better direction.  Don't try to make the problem fit the solution -- find a solution for the actual problem

All I needed to know was that there is no real solution; I used booleans to store if a button was pressed and all is working properly.

The answer to your question is that it can’t be done.  Java doesn’t control this;  the operating system does.  The operating system sends native key press events repeatedly;  Java just translates them into java.awt.event.KeyEvent objects.
The way to deal with it is to keep your own Set which tracks which keys are pressed and which are not, and update that Set in a KeyListener’s keyPressed and keyReleased methods.  Then your program can react to the keys in that Set, rather than acting directly on events.  Here’s a short example:
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashSet;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;

public class KeyPressMonitor {
    private final Collection<Integer> keysPressed = new HashSet<>();

    private final JList<String> pressedKeyList;

    private final JFrame window;

    public KeyPressMonitor() {
        pressedKeyList = new JList<>();

        JLabel input = new JLabel("Awaiting key presses");
        input.setFocusable(true);
        input.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(100, 100, 100, 100));

        input.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event) {
                if (keysPressed.add(event.getKeyCode())) {
                    processNewKeyPresses();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent event) {
                if (keysPressed.remove(event.getKeyCode())) {
                    processNewKeyPresses();
                }
            }
        });

        window = new JFrame("Key press monitor");
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.getContentPane().add(input, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        window.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(pressedKeyList),
            BorderLayout.CENTER);

        window.pack();
        window.setLocationByPlatform(true);

        input.requestFocusInWindow();
    }

    private void processNewKeyPresses() {
        pressedKeyList.setListData(
            keysPressed.stream().map(KeyEvent::getKeyText).sorted().toArray(
                String[]::new));
    }

    void show() {
        window.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> new KeyPressMonitor().show());
    }
}

